# How do I ssh on slow/flaky connections?

Tags: ssh, shell, remote

I am dealing with a really slow shell connection. It is in the cloud and I am very far from the server. My connection also breaks sometimes as it is over the internet and I may also be using shared Wifi or 3G. Is there a way to see what I type instantly? Trying to type commands and waiting for each character is atrocious.

Comment: Use "screen" to hold your session alive, so that you can reconnect when you disconnect.

Answer (score 26):

Try [Mosh](http://mosh.mit.edu/).

> **Mosh (mobile shell)**
>   Remote terminal application that allows roaming, supports intermittent connectivity, and provides intelligent local echo and line editing of user keystrokes.
>
> Mosh is a replacement for SSH. It's more robust and responsive, especially over Wi-Fi, cellular, and long-distance links.
>
> Mosh is free software, available for GNU/Linux, FreeBSD, Solaris, Mac OS X, and Android.

Comment: Caveats to mosh: (1) it's much more cpu intensive than ssh. (2) If your mosh session doesn't end normally, you'll have a leaked connection that can never be re-established. (I have to houseclean my shell box otherwise there will be dozens of processes running).

Comment: Another issue is that it is near impossible to install on linux distro like Suse (SLES). I spent hours trying to install it as either an openSuse package or compiling it from source.

Comment: $ sudo zypper in mosh (acording to the docs)

Comment: Yes that will work fine on openSuse, but a corporate/closed distro it is very tasking to install new open source projects.

Comment: NB it doesn't support scrollback (at all) so you basically have to run screen or tmux to get that.

Answer (score 10):

an alternative (and also in addition) to dmourati answer: use `screen` or `tmux` or other things, to keep sessions alive when you are disconnected. (You simply re-attach to the session after you reconnect, and see the terminal as you left it, even with full screen programs [vi, etc]). It also have many other benefits (sharing sessions with co-workers, etc)
 (as in Mosh own faq it states:

> Q: Why is my terminal's scrollback buffer incomplete?
>
> Mosh 1.2 synchronizes only the visible state of the terminal.  Mosh
>   1.3 will have complete scrollback support; see this issue and the others which are linked from there.  For now, the workaround is to use
>   screen or tmux on the remote side.

And you should also use `rsync` to copy files, without having to re-send already sent parts over the network when the connection dies.

Comment: Mosh 1.3 is out, but they haven't implemented scrollback https://github.com/mobile-shell/mosh/issues/122 you basically have to use screen or tmux underneath.

Answer (score 2):

You should see where the latency/bottleneck(s) are. You should try to get better access to infrastructure... either locally or at the provider's side. You wrap your important or critical sessions in `tmux` or `screen` multiplexers...

Please give us numbers. It takes a particularly-bad connection for simple SSH sessions to have problems... I've had to access systems on the other side of the world from an *airplane* over a VPN and still haven't had too much trouble. Is this a persistent issue? What does `traceroute` tell you?

Comment: The issue occurs on hotel wifi a lot, where there are too few routers and too many devices/laptops sharing internet access. Also shared hotel wifi is inherently pretty crummy with ping times as going through 1 or more walls really adds a lot of ms delay. That is also another major bottleneck. Similar situation occurs on 3G, where that much distance to the cell phone tower adds MS. When using SSH shells, I have to wait for each character. A MS of 200-400 can be pretty annoying, but with spikes of up to 1 second... ouch.

Answer (score 2):

For future readers of this thread, @lowellheddings' tip in his [blog](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/keep-your-linux-ssh-session-from-disconnecting/), together with the use of [screen](https://linux.die.net/man/1/screen), could help overcome this issue:

You can configure the ssh client to automatically send a protocol no-op code code every number of seconds so that the server won’t disconnect you. This setting is sometimes referred to as Keep-Alive or Stop-Disconnecting-So-Much in other clients.
Add the following line to the /etc/ssh/ssh_config file:
    ServerAliveInterval 60
...

Comment: I've done this both on client and server (ClientAliveInterval) and disabled TCPKeepAlive, but it still drops with `client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe`. Any clue?

Comment: @M.Volf broken pipe means the remote end (or a firewall in between?) decided to close the connection, so the send is now impossible (and the "pipe" between client and server is broken).   `ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=60  user@host` will try to keep the connection alive by sending a "nop" packet every 60 seconds